# Add additional disks through packer on Google Compute Engine Image

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, packer

I want to build a Google Cloud image using Packer, but can't seem to find a way for packer to add additional disks with googlecompute builder. This is required as want a persistent disk for application to store data on it.

Is it something that can be done through startup_script or any other way?

Comment: As LukeTerro suggested, GCP images are per disk.
Packer, is only for packing those disks into images.
So to achieve what you want depends on the way your planning to create VM instances from those images.

You can use Instance Templates together with a Startup Script to attach an additional disk, format on first boot and mount it. Then create an instance from the instance template. You can also consider using tools like Terraform to do the same and continue to follow you Infrastructure-as-code paradigm.


https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates/create-instance-templates

Comment: @AmirRahwane I had to turn to an ansible module to do so:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/gce_pd_module.html?fbclid=IwAR3NErydsFLdg3XkTQrVt3FfOHCcsgB2ZXMDmZvrxKkrGKGakRp0b_iiTUU

Answer (score 0):

GCE images only support one disk.
Please check [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74106832) for an open feature request to support this.